# Error al usar login de gmail - android

Tags: android

Ya me funciona el login de gmail.

El problema es que como quiero usar también login de Facebook y Twitter quiero separar las clases de cada una y solamente llamarlas dentro de mi fragmento `login`.

Este es un fragmento de `login`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


/**
 * Created by Principal on 03/06/2016.
 */
public class Login extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private ImageView profile;
    private LoginButton sign_in_button_gmail;
    private View view;
    LoginGmail loginGmail = new LoginGmail(view);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getContext());
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
       // sign_in_button_gmail = (LoginButton)  view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_gmail);

        /*Codigo de facebook*/
        info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        profile = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile);
        setFacebookListener();
        //Fin login facebook
        loginGmail.Create(savedInstanceState);

        return view;
    }


    private void setFacebookListener() {

        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                                   GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {
                                            try {
                                                manager.setPreferences(getContext(), "name2", object.getString("name"));
                                                manager.setPreferences(getContext(), "idUser", object.getString("id"));
                                                Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                    }
                                });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

        setImageProfile();
    }


    public void setImageProfile(){

        String idUserFace=manager.getPreferences(getContext(),"name2");
        String tokenFace=manager.getPreferences(getContext(),"idUser");

        info.setText(
                "Usuario: "
                        + idUserFace
                        + "\n" +
                        "Auth id: "
                        + tokenFace
        );

       /* CargaImagenes nuevaTarea = new CargaImagenes(profile);
        System.out.println("http://graph.facebook.com/"+tokenFace+"/picture?type=large");
        nuevaTarea.execute("http://graph.facebook.com/"+tokenFace+"/picture?type=large");*/
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    /*-------------------------------------------------*/
}
```

Y en esta clase tengo el código para usar gmail:

```
package Views.Login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

/**
 * Created by em645 on 22/8/2016.
 */
public class LoginGmail extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    /* Indica si hay una resolución de ConnectionResult en proceso */
    public boolean mIsResolving = false;
    /* Indica si debemos resolver automáticamente ConnectionResults cuando es posible */
    public boolean mShouldResolve = false;
    /* Claves para almacenar variables de instancias en savedInstanceState */
    private static final String KEY_IS_RESOLVING = "is_resolving";
    private static final String KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE = "should_resolve";

    /* TextView para mostrar el estado actual (identificado, no identificado, desconectado, etc.) */
    public TextView mStatus;
    /* Cliente para acceder a Google APIs */
    public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static final String TAG = "LoginGmail";
    private View viewLoginGmail;


    /* Código de petición para la identificación */
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    public LoginGmail(View view){
        viewLoginGmail=view;
    }
    public void Create(Bundle savedInstanceState){

           // Restauramos a partir de los datos almacenados
           if (savedInstanceState != null) {
               mIsResolving = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_RESOLVING);
               mShouldResolve = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE);
           }

           // Configuramos los listeners de los botones cuando hacemos click en ellos
        viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_gmail).setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

           // Ampliamos el tamaño del botón de login
           ((SignInButton) viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_gmail)).setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

           // Al principio el botón para identificarnos está deshabilitado, hasta que sepamos si el proceso de autenticación se lleva a cabo o no correctamente
        viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_gmail).setEnabled(false);

           // Configuramos el TextView para el estado actual
           mStatus = (TextView) viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.status);

           // Creamos el objeto GoogleApiClient con acceso a la información básica del perfil de la cuenta
           mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext())
                   .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                   .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                   .addApi(Plus.API)
                   .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                   .build();
       }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        //El método onConnected indica que una cuenta estaba seleccionada en el dispositivo,
        //que la cuenta seleccionada tiene los permisos necesarios para nuestra aplicación y
        //que podemos establecer una conexión con los servicios de Google Play.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected:" + bundle);

        // Muestra la interfaz de identificación
        updateUI(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //Se ha perdido la conexión con los servicios de Google Play. El objeto GoogleApiClient
        //automáticamente intentará reconectarse. Cualquier elemento visual que dependa de la
        // conexión con Google APIs se debería ocultar o deshabilitar hasta que el método onConnected
        //sea ejecutado de nuevo.
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended:" + i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //Puede que no se pueda llevar a cabo la conexión con los servicios de Google Play. El
        // usuario necesita seleccionar una cuenta, aceptar los permisos necesarios o resolver
        // un error para poder identificarse.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult((Activity) getBaseContext(), RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "No se pudo resolver ConnectionResult.", e);
                    mIsResolving = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                // Si no se puede procesar el resultado de la conexión, mostrar al usuario un
                // mensaje de error.
                showErrorDialog(connectionResult);
            }
        } else {
            // Muestra la interfaz de usuario no identificado.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    private void showErrorDialog(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        int errorCode = connectionResult.getErrorCode();

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(errorCode)) {
            // Muestra el mensaje de error por defecto de los servicios de Google Play.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, (Activity) getBaseContext(), RC_SIGN_IN,
                    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            mShouldResolve = false;
                            updateUI(false);
                        }
                    }).show();
        } else {
            // Si no existe un mensaje de error por defecto por parte de los servicios de Google
            // Play, mostrar un mensaje al usuario.
            String errorString = getString(R.string.play_services_error_fmt, errorCode);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), errorString,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mShouldResolve = false;
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }


    public void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            // Muestra el nombre del usuario identificado
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (currentPerson != null) {
                String name = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                mStatus.setText("Nombre de la persona"+ name);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.error_null_person));
                mStatus.setText("Error de la autenticacion");
            }

            // Modifica la visibilidad del botón
            viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_gmail).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // Muestra el mensaje de no identificado
            mStatus.setText("Muestra el mensaje de no identificado");

            // Modifica la visibilidad del botón
            viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_gmail).setEnabled(true);
            viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_gmail).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_IS_RESOLVING, mIsResolving);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE, mShouldResolve);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // Si la resolución del error no fue satisfactoria no debemos intentar resolver errores sucesivos
            /*if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mShouldResolve = false;
            }*/

            mIsResolving = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.sign_in_button_gmail:
                // El usuario hace clic en el botón para autenticarse, de forma que comienza
                // proceso de autenticación y automáticamente se intenta resolver cualquier
                // problema que pueda surgir.
                mStatus.setText("Autenticandose");

                mShouldResolve = true;
                 mGoogleApiClient.connect();

                break;
            case R.id.sign_out_button:
                // Limpia la cuenta por defecto de forma que el objeto GoogleApiClient no se
                // intente conectar en el futuro con ella automáticamente.

                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }

                updateUI(false);
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                // Eliminar todos los permisos y limpiar la cuenta por defecto. El usuario
                // tendrá que pasar de nuevo por la pantalla de consentimiento para autenticarse.

                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }

                updateUI(false);
                break;

        }
    }    
}
```

Este es el error:

```
 // Configuramos los listeners de los botones cuando hacemos click en ellos
                     viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_gmail).setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);





   PID: 6744
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at   Views.Login.LoginGmail.Create(LoginGmail.java:76)
```

Comment: Estaría fantástico que publiques el error que te muestra en el LogCat.

Comment: Creo que la lógica que estas empleando esta mal, recuerda que la actividad se crea primero que el fragmento, por lo cual la clase LoginGmail siempre va a ser nula porque haces la instancia hasta que se crea el fragmento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que `sign_in_button_gmail` es el primer elemento que busca en el contenedor y no lo encuentra en la vista o la vista donde tratas de buscarlo tiene un valor nulo,  por eso envía el error `NullPointerException` ,

Si ves en la clase `Login` estas instanciando `LoginGmail` con una vista que tiene un valor null:

```
 LoginGmail loginGmail = new LoginGmail(view);
```

por esa razón cuando tratas de buscar el elemento `sign_in_button_gmail` envia un `NullPointerException` ya que `viewLoginGmail` tiene un valor null. 
:

```
 public LoginGmail(View view){
        viewLoginGmail=view;
    }

...
...
viewLoginGmail.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button_gmail).setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
```

Comment: Perfecto!.. muchas gracias!